# Delete on nested array with jq

Tags: arrays, json, nested, jq

this is my data structure:

```
[
    {
        "name": "name1",
        "organizations": [
            {
                "name": "name2",
                "spaces": [
                    {
                        "name": "name3",
                        "otherkey":"otherval"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "name4",
                        "otherkey":"otherval"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "name21",
        "organizations": [
            {
                "name": "name22",
                "spaces": [
                    {
                        "name": "name23",
                        "otherkey":"otherval"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "name24",
                        "otherkey":"otherval"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

i just want to keep name=name1, remove the nested array object with name=name4 and want to keep the rest of the object intact. I tried with map(select) but this will just give me the full object. Is it possible to work with del on specific subarrays and keep the rest as it is?

result should be the following. in addition i want to avoid enumeration all attributes to keep on outer objects:

```
[
    {
        "name": "name1",
        "organizations": [
            {
                "name": "name2",
                "spaces": [
                    {
                        "name": "name3",
                        "otherkey":"otherval"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

any idea? thanks!

Answer (score 5):

A very targeted solution would be:

```
path(.[0].organizations[0].spaces) as $target
| (getpath($target) | map(select(.name != "name4"))) as $new
| setpath($target; $new)
```

If permissible, though, you might consider:

```
walk(if type == "object" and .spaces|type == "array"
     then .spaces |= map(select(.name != "name4"))
     else . end)
```

or:

```
del(.. | .spaces? // empty | .[] | select(.name == "name4") )
```

(If your jq does not have `walk/1` then its jq definition can easily be found by googling.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below and it will remove the `"name": "name4"` array only.

```
jq 'del(.[] | .organizations? | .[] | .spaces?|.[] | select(.name? == "name4"))' yourJsonFile.json
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using **select**, **reduce**, **tostream** and **delpaths**

```
map(  
    select(.name == "name1")
  | reduce (tostream|select(length==2)) as [$p,$v] (
      .
    ; if [$p[-1],$v] == ["name","name4"] then delpaths([$p[:-1]]) else . end
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I took a similar approach as @peak but inverted it, so instead of selecting what you want and setting that in the output we're selecting what we don't want and deleting it.

```
[path(.organizations[0].spaces[]| select(.name == "name4")] as $trash | delpaths($trash)
```